# Update translateParams in ng2-translate directive

Tags: angular, ng2-translate

Given a translation string such as:

```
"TIMEOUT": "Timeout in {{value}} seconds."
```

Is it possible to bind `value` in such a way that it will trigger `ng2-translate` to update the translated string when the underlying parameter changes?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';

@Component({
    template: `<span translate [translateParams]="{ value: countdown }">TIMEOUT</span>
        <span>{{ countdown }}</span>
        <span>{{ message }}</span>`
})
export class TimeoutComponent {
    countdown: number = 10;
    message: string;
    constructor(private translationService: TranslateService) {
        let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            this.countdown--;
            if (this.countdown <= 0) { clearInterval(intervalId); }
            console.log(this.countdown);
            this.translationService.get('TIMEOUT', { value: this.countdown }).subscribe((result) => this.message = result);
         }, 500);
    }
}
```

The above component will display `Timeout in 10 seconds.` statically, but the second span (and console) will show the value decrementing as you'd expect.

The way I've worked around this (as shown above) is to use the `TranslationService` to fetch the translated string on every tick of the interval, and update a bound `message` property on the component within the template.